# UIAlertView with subview animating to new view crashes app

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uialertview

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Congratulations" message:message delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"View", nil];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 100, 80, 80)];
NSString *imagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [Array objectAtIndex:x]];
UIImage *bkgImg = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:imagePath ofType:@"png"]];
imageView.image = bkgImg;
[bkgImg release];
[alert addSubview:imageView];
[imageView release];
[alert show];
[alert release];
```

That is the code that I am using to create the alert view.  Currently, I have it set up so if the user presses one of the buttons, it will load up a new viewcontroller. It worked fine until I added a subview to the UIAlertView. Now, whenever it animates to the new screen, it just crashes the program.  I am fairly new to iPhone development and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the crash log ? It may contains information to help to find the source of crash.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing:

```
UIImage *bkgImg = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:imagePath ofType:@"png"]];
...
[bkgImg release];
```

But `+imageWithContentsOfFile` returns an autoreleased UIImage instance, so you should **not** release it yourself. What probably is happening is the NSAutoreleasePool sending a `-release` to an object that has already been deallocated, causing the app to crash later on.

I would recommend taking a good look at http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html (or equivalent iPhone docs if those exist).